# Firebase functions saving JSON to local file

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage

I have a firebase functions where I create a JSON :

```
var tempJSONObject = {
  testing: "why are we testing",
  anothertest:"constanttesting"
}
```

and I have a temp file:

```
 const tempFilePath = path.join(os.tmpdir(), data.jokeid);
```

how do I save my JSON to this temporary file,so I can upload the file to firebase storage? I have to do this since when I pass the JSON directly to bucket.upload(),it asks me for a file path.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to save it to a file at all.  You can simply stringify the object with [JSON.stringify()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify), then upload that string to the bucket with [File.createWriteStream()](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/storage/latest/File.html#createWriteStream), writing the string value directly to the provided stream.

Comment: is there more than just File.createWriteStream()? How do I specify which file to write to, and which file to upload?

Comment: The API documentation that I linked to has everything you need, include an example. It's very flexible, and you will need to understand nodejs streams.

Comment: When I use JSON.stringify() and pass that I get: The "path" argument must be one of type string, Buffer, or URL. Received type object

Comment: If you have a new question, please post it separately, showing the new code that isn't working the way you expect.